# Trying to Upgrade Haskell stack

Tags: haskell, command-line, haskell-stack

I have Haskell stack installed on my computer and when I type in `stack --version` I get

```
    Version 1.5.1 x86_64
    Compiled with:
```

and it's a bunch of different files. When I run `stack upgrade` I get

```
Downloading from: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v2.1.3/stack-2.1.3-linux-x86_64-static.tar.gz
    Download complete, testing executable
    Version 2.1.3, Git revision 636e3a759d51127df2b62f90772def126cdf6d1f (7735 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.2

    WARNING: Installation path /root/.local/bin not found on the PATH environment variable
    New stack executable available at /root/.local/bin/stack
```

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: @Z-Y.L I want to upgrade stack to it's latest version

Comment: Then what's your problem? I seems you have installed successfully, except that you haven't set the environment variable. Do as the message suggests.

Answer (score 3):

It has upgraded correctly, the warning it shows mean that `/root/.local/bin` directory is not in the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable.

For example, in my case, if I run `stack path | grep local-bin-path` it shows:

`local-bin-path: /home/anler/.local/bin`

that is, I have it installed under my user home directory and I can check that path is in my `PATH` environment variable by running: `$(echo $PATH | grep -q '\/home\/anler\/.local\/bin') && echo yes || echo no`